# Como dar update no banco de dados PDO após executar uma função (countdown) Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, pdo

Estou fazendo um **countdown** Javascript, e gostaria que quando a contagem fosse **== 0**, executasse um **update no banco de dados** onde iria **agregar um valor**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var count=new Number();

var count=<?php echo $time ?>; //Valor da variável do banco de dados

function start(){
if ((count -1) >=0) {
count=count - 1;
if (count == 0) 
{       
// Quando count == 0 Adiciona(UPDATE) valor +10 dentro de uma variável do banco de dados            
}           
tempo.innerText=count;
setTimeout('start();', 1000);
}
}
</script>
```

### EDIT ##

Estou usando esse código no momento e não está dando certo

**HTML**

```
<body onload="start();">
<div id="tempo"></div>
<form method="POST" action="insert.php" id="my_form">
    <input type="text" name="id_user" value="ID_Que_Eu_Quero_Passar" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" name="id_view" value="ID_Que_Eu_Quero_Passar2" style="display: none;">
</form>
</body>
```

**JQUERY AJAX**

```
var count=new Number();
var count=10;
function start(){
    if ((count -1) >=0) {
        count=count - 1;
        if (count == 0) {
$.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('insert.php') 
    ,async: true 
    ,cache: false 
    ,type: $(this).attr('POST') 
    ,data: $(this).serialize() 
    ,dataType: 'json' 
    ,success: function(data){
       console.log("Update aconteceu");
        if(data.success == 'yes'){
            alert('Gol!');
        }
        else{
            alert('insert failed!');
        }
    }
    ,error: function(){
    }
    ,complete: function(){
    }});    }
    tempo.innerText=count;
        setTimeout('start();', 1000);}}
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
echo $_POST['ID_Que_Eu_Quero_Passar'];
echo $_POST['ID_Que_Eu_Quero_Passar'];
?>
```

Comment: Dentro do `if (count == 0) ` você pode fazer uma requisição AJAX para um script PHP que faça o INSERT no banco.

Comment: @Marcos estou tentando isso mas até agora sem sucesso, não estou conseguindo fazer o ajax executar o update

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o código do AJAX e do PHP que você está utilizando.

Comment: @Marcos pronto amigo, editei e botei tudo ali

Comment: Se você fizer um `var_dump` do $_POST, o que vem?

Comment: @Marcos aparece valor indefinido do $_POST, mas o problema esta ali dentro do `if count {}` eu acho, por que o contador esta travando no 1, e não executa o ajax

Answer (score 0):

O `if (count == 0)` pois ele deve estar fora do `if ((count -1) >=0)`:

```
var count=new Number();
var count=10;
function start(){
    if ((count -1) >=0) {
        count=count - 1;
    }
    if (count == 0) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('insert.php') 
            ,async: true 
            ,cache: false 
            ,type: $(this).attr('POST') 
            ,data: $(this).serialize() 
            ,dataType: 'json' 
            ,success: function(data){
                console.log("Update aconteceu");
                if(data.success == 'yes'){
                    alert('Gol!');
                }
                else{
                    alert('insert failed!');
                }
            }
            ,error: function(){
            }
            ,complete: function(){
            }
        });
    }
    setTimeout('start();', 1000);
}

start();
```